# Getting org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Unable to obtain an object lock on "null"

Tags: java, jpa, db2, websphere, optimistic-locking

I am getting below exception while doing EntityManager.find(). We are using DB2 database and WAS 8.0 server for our application. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1709309 nonfatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Unable to obtain an object lock on "null".
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4930)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4908)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary.newStoreException(DB2Dictionary.java:603)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:136)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:110)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:62)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedSQLStoreQuery$PreparedSQLExecutor.executeQuery(PreparedSQLStoreQuery.java:139)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1012)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:870)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:801)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:315)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:331)

... 116 more

Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-913, SQLSTATE=57033, SQLERRMC=00C90088;00000304;ODNC001 .SNCPC145.X'200D65' '.X'43', DRIVER=4.15.134 {prepstmnt -1803801027 
SELECT a.column1 
FROM table_test a 
WHERE (a.column2 = ? AND a.column3 = ?) 
[params=(String) 00000, (String) 000011]} [code=-913, state=57033]
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:281)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:265)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$700(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:72)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:1183)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:284)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JDBCStoreManager.java:1787)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:274)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedSQLStoreQuery$PreparedSQLExecutor.executeQuery(PreparedSQLStoreQuery.java:118)
... 123 more
```

Answer (score 0):

sqlode -913 with SQLERRMC=00C90088 means that your connection experienced a DEADLOCK.

If your Db2-server is running on Z/OS, then ask your DBA for help to find the other Db2-connection and the SQL-statements running in both transactions.The access-plans and isolation levels used by both connections are also relevant, as are any applicable lock timeouts. The Db2-server DBA has access to diagnostic tools to help you.

There are many hits online giving advice on how to reduce the likelihood of Db2 deadlocks, so do your research.

You will need to know the isolation level being used by the Websphere connection (or package, or SQL-statement(s)), and all the statements in the Db2-transaction for your connection.

The other tokens in the message are also relevant i.e. ODNC001.SNCPC145 may be the involved table.

The version of the jdbc type4 driver being used by your Websphere is out of date (looks like it is from a Db2 v10.1 fixpack 5 build) so consider getting that upgraded to a current version.